# How to build json params in Httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I have to send a post request in httparty and get response
my json params are

```
    {
  "webhook": {
    "topic": "shop/update",
    "address": "http://2350d6c0.ngrok.io/shopify_stores/update_shop_info",
    "format": "json"
  }
}
```

And i am using httparty params as

```
begin
          response = HTTParty.post("#{url}",
          { 
            :body => [
                {
                    "webhook" => {
                        "topic" => "shop\/update",
                        "address" => "http:\/\/15ec3a12.ngrok.io\/shopify_stores\/update_shop_info", #place your url here
                        "format" => "json" 
                   }
                }
                        ].to_json,
            :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
          })
          byebug
        rescue HTTParty::Error

    end
```

but it repsonse is

Required parameter missing or invalid

Comment: Ok. Is there some part in the controller where it says `def something_params`, under `private`section? If so, can you put that in your question?

Comment: I am not using them just send a post request to server and saving reponse

Answer (score 1):

The smoothest way to work with HTTParty is by creating clients instead of using it in a procedural fashion.

```
class MyApiClient
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'example.com'

  format :json

  # this is just an example of how it is commonly done
  def initalize(api_key = nil)
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def post_something(data)
    self.class.post("/some_path", data)
  end
end
```

This will let you do:

```
client = MyApiClient.new()
puts client.post_something({ foo: "bar" })
```

You don't need handle setting headers or encoding the body - HTTParty will handle that for you. Thats kind of the whole point of the library - if you want to grunt it out procedurally just use [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) which is part of the stdlib.